# Quiero hacer una base de datos en consola usando el servidor de XAMPP en el sistema operativo de macOS, pero me sale el siguiente mensaje en consola:

Tags: xampp, mariadb

MariaDB [(none)]> create database alumnos;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'alumnos'

Comment: Te lo pone en el mensage, el usuario @localhost no tiene acceso a la base de datos alumnos

Comment: eso es lo que quiero solucionar, como logro obtener acceso?

Comment: Parece ser que iniciaste el cliente sin un usuario, ¿corriste el siguiente comando `mysql -u root -p` para entrar?

Answer (score 0):

Debes de primero iniciar sesion con el

```
mysql -u root
```

y luego ya crear la Base de Datos

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).